# How to decrypting string in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8, cryptojs

Tried to decript the mail as a string in angular 8 but not working.How to do it in angular 8.
I have encripted email in node js and passing the encripted data by url and tying to decript in angular 8.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sha3s1

Encripted in nodeJs:

```
function encrypt(mailid) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-cbc', 'd6f3Efeq');
    var crypted = cipher.update(mailid, 'utf8', 'hex')
    crypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return crypted;
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js'; 
ngOnInit(){ 

  this._Activatedroute.paramMap.subscribe(params => { 
// Encrypt
var encriptdata = params.get('mailid'); //test@gmail.com 
// Decrypt
var bytes  = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encriptdata, 'secret key 123');
var decryptedData = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); 
console.log(decryptedData);  

 });
}
```

Comment: This issue doesn't seem to have anything in common with Angular.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph: Check my question now

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: I've checked your code on stackblitz, your mistake was you just pass a string to decrypt method.

Comment: @DiakoAmir:How to encript mailid in nodejs and how to decript in angular 8?

Comment: I'll give you an example in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample how you can encrypt and decrypt with CryptoJS

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase", {
  format: JsonFormatter
});
​
encrypted
> {
    ct: "tZ4MsEnfbcDOwqau68aOrQ==",
    iv: "8a8c8fd8fe33743d3638737ea4a00698",
    s: "ba06373c8f57179c"
  };
​
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase", {
  format: JsonFormatter
});
​
decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
> "Message";
```

Reference: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#ciphers